# Did the Infinity Gauntlet always have a cost?

Tags: marvel, comics

Did the Infinity Gauntlet in Marvel comics have the same draining cost as in the movies? Or that is something that is also another thing the Cinematic Universe nerfed?

Comment: MCU missed logic: I snapped my fingers to pay the cost of the Snap and bring everyone back to life/kill them all/whatever. I snapped my fingers to transfer my soul and consciousness to an exact duplicate of my present body+stuff while letting my old body pay the cost of the Snap. I snapped my fingers to give my body Hulk-like/Thanos-like resilience along with all the other things during the Snap.

Comment: @thelethalcarrot why remove those tags? They help specify the topic of this question.

Comment: @Robert The [[tag:the-infinity-gauntlet]] tag is for the comic book series so not applicable here. The [[tag:infinity-stones]] one is perhaps more relevant but even then this is more about using the full gauntlet than the stones themselves.

Comment: [It sure did!](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Marvel-Infinity-Gauntlet-Articulated-Electronic/dp/B07822SW6D?ref_=ast_sto_dp) But then [it got cheaper!](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Marvel-Infinity-Gauntlet-Electronic-Fist/dp/B07M6L4LKJ?ref_=ast_sto_dp)

Comment: @Lexible missed flawed assumption: the Infinity Stones are all-powerful magic, meaning none of those ideas work. This is Thor's hammer all over again.

Answer (score 8):

The full Infinity Gauntlet in the comics originally didn’t have a cost attached to it, Thanos could use it freely. The below page is the first we see of Thanos again after the snap in the first issue of *The Infinity Gauntlet*.

[image: Thanos stands with the full gauntlet in front of his brother with it in his face smiling away who he has chained to a chair; Mephitso stands off to the side]